# Tolerance Interval

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Show that a tolerance interval is necessarily distribution-free.

Do you know where can I find the proof or any helpful suggestion?

Comment: How would you calculate a particular tolerance interval?  If it depends solely on the sample (e.g. based on some of the order statistics) then you have made no assumption about the distribution, and so the same sample from a different distribution would give you the same tolerance interval